# How to handle paging with RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

I'm looking into converting my android app to use Rxjava for network requests. I currently access a webservice similar to:

```
getUsersByKeyword(String query, int limit, int offset)
```

As I understand it, Observables are a "push" rather than a "pull" interface. So here's how I understand things to work out:

- app registers with service, getting Observable for query
- results are pushed to app
- app deals with results
- when app wants more results ...?

This is where things break down for me. Previously I would just ask the webservice for exactly what I want, make the query again with the offset. But in this case that would involve creating another Observable and subscribing to it, kind of defeating the point.

How should I handle paging in my app? (It's an android app, but I don't think that is relevant).

Answer (score 11):

It was hard rock!)
So we have request to network: 
`getUsersByKeyword(String query, int limit, int offset)`  
and this request return for example 
 `List< Result >`  
If we use RetroFit for networking that request will look: 
`Observable< List< Result >> getUsersByKeyword(String query, int limit, int offset)`  
As result we want to get all `Result` from server. 
So it will look like this

```
int page = 50;
int limit = page;
Observable
                .range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
                .concatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<List<Result>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<List<Result>> call(Integer integer) {
                        return getUsersByKeyword(query, integer * page, limit);
                    }
                })
                .takeWhile(new Func1<List<Result>, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(List<Result> results) {
                        return !results.isEmpty();
                    }
                })
                .scan(new Func2< List<Result>, List<Result>, List<Result>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Result> call(List<Result> results, List< Result> results2) {
                        List<Result> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.addAll(results);
                        list.addAll(results2);
                        return list;
                    }
                })
                .last()
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Result>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Results> results) {
                    }
                });
```

Code was TESTED!

Comment: Although this solution works, there are couple of things I would note.
1. If `getUsersByKeyword` returns less items than page size (50 here), then 1 excessive call for next page will be made anyway.
2. If the `getUsersByKeyword` returns no items for the 1 page, then the exception will be thrown: `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. Consider using `.lastOrDefault(new ArrayList<>())` instead of `.last()`

Comment: Thanks for the reference @xoxol_89. The subject of this particular question is not related to RecyclerView. The task was to load all pages one-by-one without any events outside that trigger loading of next portion.

Answer (score 5):

So, if this is one-way paging, here's a pattern you might try. This code hasn't been run or compiled, but I've tried to over-annotate in order to explain what's going on.

```java
private static final int LIMIT = 50;

// Given: Returns a stream of dummy event objects telling us when
// to grab the next page. This could be from a click or wherever.
Observable<NextPageEvent> getNextPageEvents();  

// Given:
// The search query keywords. Each emission here means a new top-level
// request;
Observable<String> queries;

queries.switchMap((query) -> getNextPageEvents()
        // Ignore 'next page' pokes when unable to take them.
        .onBackPressureDrop()
        // Seed with the first page.
        .startWith(new NextPageEvent())
        // Increment the page number on each request.
        .scan(0, (page, event) -> page + 1) 
        // Request the page from the server.
        .concatMap((page) -> getUsersByKeyword(query, LIMIT, LIMIT * page)
                // Unroll Observable<List<User> into Observable<User>
                .concatMap((userList) -> Observable.from(userList))
                .retryWhen(/** Insert your favorite retry logic here. */))
        // Only process new page requests sequentially.
        .scheduleOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
        // Trampoline schedules on the 'current thread', so we make sure that's
        // a background IO thread.
        .scheduleOn(Schedulers.io());
```

That should let the 'next page events' signal trigger a load of the next page's data each time, as well as not jumping pages should it encounter an error loading one. It also restarts completely at the top level if it receives a new search query. If I (or somebody else?) has time, I'd like to check my assumptions about the trampoline and backpressure and make sure it blocks any attempt to prematurely fetch the next page while one is loading.

Comment: Are you sure scheduling on `trampoline` followed by `io` works like that? I also saw [your discussion over on Github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2479), but couldn't draw any conclusions from there.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this and it's actually not that hard.

The approach is to model every first request (offset 0) in a firstRequestsObservable. To make it easy, you can make this as a PublishSubject where you call `onNext()` to feed in the next request, but there are smarter non-Subject ways of doing it (e.g., if requests are done when a button is clicked, then the requestObservable is the clickObservable mapped through some operators).

Once you have `firstRequestsObservable` in place, you can make `responseObservable` by flatMapping from `firstRequestsObservable` and so forth, to make the service call.

Now here comes the trick: make another observable called `subsequentRequestsObservable` which is mapped from `responseObservable`, incrementing the offset (for this purpose it's good to include, in the response data, the offset of the originating request). Once you introduce this observable, you now have to change the definition of `responseObservable` so that it depends also on `subsequentRequestsObservable`. You then get a circular dependency like this:

firstRequestsObservable -> responseObservable -> subsequentRequestsObservable -> responseObservable -> subsequentRequestsObservable -> ...

To break this cycle, you probably want to include a `filter` operator in the definition of `subsequentRequestsObservable`, filtering out those cases where the offset would pass the "total" limit. The circular dependency also means that you *need* to have one of those being a Subject, otherwise it would be impossible to declare the observables. I recommend `responseObservable` to be that Subject.

So, all in all, you first initialize responseObservable as a Subject, then declare firstRequestsObservable, then declare subsequentRequestsObservable as the result of passing responseObservable through some operators. responseObservable can then be "fed in" by using `onNext`.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample app on github showing how this should be implemented? Or at least post here some code for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind making this a bit more clear? How does the subscriber of the stream request the next page?

Comment: Don't think about subscribers doing stuff. The approach is to model all of the events as Observables and Subjects. There is no "subscriber requesting the next page", there is an Observable representing all the first page requests, and an Observable requesting all 'next' page requests.

Comment: I guess I'm unclear then of how the Observable knows that it is time to get the next page. Say I am displaying the results in a list, and when I scroll to the current bottom, I want to get more results. How is this sort of behavior achieved with this approach?

Comment: Make `requestMoreResultsObservable` depend on `scrollBottomHappenedObservable` and `responseObservable`. Everything should be modeled as an Observable. Something like `requestMoreResultsObservable = responseObservable.sample(scrollBottomHappenedObservable).map(// get the last response, increment offset, return request url`. Read the answer again. Think only in marble diagrams, e.g., http://www.rxmarbles.com , imagine that observables are spreadsheet cells and make them depend on each other. It appears that what you need is a change of mindset to get old imperative habits away.

Comment: I think it'd be better to provide simple example how to implement this. I still can't figure out the idea behind chaining these observable to implement paging.

Comment: Building such example takes a lot of my time, I'd rather try to answer specific questions you might have. The stackoverflow answer is already thorough and not even the question had code, so I'm trying to answer questions rather than building it for you.

Comment: @AndréStaltz you're right, it will take some time to prepare an example, but without the example your thought are rather useless because most of us couldn't understand your concept. That's probably why your answer is not accepted and the only +1 is from me.

Comment: Which part was not understood?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, I assume your questions is more how to apply RxJava in your Android application rather than on the back end (although it's possible to apply too but not as typical as the front end). 
And i'm not very sure if this example is a typical use case for using reactive functional programming (RFP) model except for the clean code constructs.

Each stream below is an Observable. Personally, I would like to think it as stream as it's easy to reason about the events.
Pagination flow can be represented by 6 streams:

```
firstPageStream -f-------------------> // this is actually to produce very first event to obtain the first page result. The event can come from a touch in one of the screen that navigates to this list screen.
nextPageStream  -----n-------n-------> // this is the source of events coming from Next button 'touch' actions
prevPageStream  ---------p-------p---> // this is the source of events coming from Previous button 'touch' actions
requestStream   -r---r---r---r---r---> // this is to consume the signal from 3 streams above and spawn events (r) which create a query and pagination details i.e.: offset and limit
responseStream  -R---R---R---R---R---> // this is to take each r and invoke your web service getUsersByKeyword() then spawn the response (R)
```

The above streams can be represented in pseudo code (JS style) below (it would be fairly easy to translate to RxJava or other languages)

```
firstPageStream = Observable.just(0); // offset=0
nextPageStream = Observable.fromEvent(nextButton, 'touch')
                           .map(function() {
                              offset = offset + limit;
                              return offset;
                            });
prevPageStream = Observable.fromEvent(prevButton, 'touch')
                           .map(function() {
                              offset = offset - limit; // TODO some check here
                              return offset;
                            });
requestStream = Observable.merge(firstPageStream, nextPageStream, prevPageStream)
                            .map(function(offsetValue) {
                               return {offset : offsetValue, limit: limit};
                            });
responseStream = requestStream.flatMap(function(pagination) {
                                return webservice.getUsersByKeyword(query, pagination.offset, pagination.limit); // assume this is async response
                              });
responseStream.subscribe(function(result) {
  // use result to render the display
});
```

PS1: I have not tested the above code. I'm learning RFP so I just try to think in reactive way by writing down. Welcome any suggestion.

PS2: I'm highly influenced by https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754 for the way to explain reactive streams.