# Async remove of documents with key starting with a certain string

Tags: java, couchbase

I'm trying to remove all documents from my bucket whose keys start with a certain string.

My view is:

```
private void createAndPublishCacheView()
{
 List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
 views.add(DefaultView.create("cache_view_by_key", "function (doc, meta) { emit(meta.id, null) }"));

 DesignDocument designDoc   = DesignDocument.create("cache_doc", views);
 this.cacheBucket.bucketManager().upsertDesignDocument(designDoc);
}
```

And my removeAll method is (remove a document if its key starts with 'callId'):

```
public void removeAll(String callId) throws Exception
{
 final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
 ViewQuery query            = cacheView.startKeyDocId(callId);

 bucket.async()
    .query(query)
    .doOnNext(new Action1<AsyncViewResult>() 
              {
               @Override
               public void call(AsyncViewResult viewResult) 
               {
                if (!viewResult.success()) throw new RuntimeException();
               }
              }
             )
    .flatMap(new Func1<AsyncViewResult, Observable<AsyncViewRow>>() 
             {
              @Override
              public Observable<AsyncViewRow> call(AsyncViewResult viewResult) 
              {
               return viewResult.rows();
              }
             }
            )
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<AsyncViewRow>() 
               {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() { latch.countDown(); }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) { throw new RuntimeException(t.getMessage()); }

                @Override
                public void onNext(AsyncViewRow viewRow) 
                { 
                 System.out.println("viewRow.id() = " + viewRow.id());
                 bucket.remove(viewRow.id());
                }
               }
              );

 latch.await();
 }
```

I'm a beginner with Observables. If the onNext method is:

```
  public void onNext(AsyncViewRow viewRow) 
                { 
                 System.out.println("viewRow.id() = " + viewRow.id());
                 bucket.remove(viewRow.id());
                }
```

Then only several documents are printed on console and deleted, and I receive a:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:75)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.remove(CouchbaseBucket.java:486)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.remove(CouchbaseBucket.java:466)
at com.ventusproxy.tests.couchbase.TestCB$3.onNext(TestCB.java:167)
at com.ventusproxy.tests.couchbase.TestCB$3.onNext(TestCB.java:1)
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:130)
```

If the onNext method is:

```
  public void onNext(AsyncViewRow viewRow) 
                { 
                 System.out.println("viewRow.id() = " + viewRow.id());
                 bucket.async().remove(viewRow.id());
                }
```

Then all documents are printed on console but they are not deleted.

Can anybody help me?

Furthermore, I'm not sure if this is the most efficent way to remove a big set of documents.

Thanks,

Joan.

Comment: In fact, I also see that "cacheView.startKeyDocId(callId)" is not filtering the records starting with 'callId', I'm getting all records printed on the onNext method.

Comment: As a side comment: there's no need to emit document's id as keys (that way you do in the view) - these are always emitted (and you're actually using them).

when you get a timeout - is it always on the same document? how long is the timeout?

Comment: I always receive this timeout after reading 7 or 8 documents. I tried to set up several timeouts to this query (2, 5, 10 seconds), and they are always reached. In additon, the 'cacheView.startKeyDocId(callId)' is not filtering the keys, I'm not sure why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with what you're trying to do:

1. The `startKeyDocId` method doesn't actually do what you think it does. Use
   `startKey(callId)`.
2. Only specifying the start key will return ALL results greater than
   the parameter, not only results that start with that exact key. View
   queries compare the keys lexicographically in ascending order, so you'll get all strings greater than `callId`. You should specify both
   the start and end keys, as well as inclusive end, in your query to limit it properly. So `cacheView.startKey(callId).endKey(calldId).inclusiveEnd(true)` (typing from memory, syntax might be slightly off.)
3. You're trying to retrieve all matching keys at once. If there are
   many results, the query will time out simply because it will take
   too long to return all the results. If you expect many results (say
   over 1000) you should use paging to retrieve and process them in
   chunks. Here is a good example of how to implement paging with Observables in RxJava: [How to handle paging with RxJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321023/how-to-handle-paging-with-rxjava)
4. You call the View query asynchronously but use a blocking remove call. Instead of subscribing to the result of the async query call, you should `flatMap` it into `bucket.async().remove(row.id())` - then you can subscribe to the result of all the asynchronous remove calls, add some retry and error handling logic, etc. Look here regarding implementing retry and error handling: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/observables.html#story-h2-10 (Specifically scroll to the `retryWhen` example.)
5. Finally, if you're using Couchbase 4.0, you can replace the whole thing with the following N1QL query: `DELETE FROM bucket WHERE META(bucket).id like 'ABC%';`

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for your response. Yes, I tried with N1ql and delete statement, but I was not using it because I though it was still experimental in CB4.

Comment: As you say, DML statements like DELETE, are considered beta in Couchbase 4.0. However, something simple like that will work fine, unless you happen to have to many documents that match the query condition. In that case you can break it into chunks as well, by specifying the max number of documents to match in the DELETE statement.